# Evaluation of undefined limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am supposed to evaluate this limit.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} \ln(\ln x)}{\sqrt[3]{(2x+3)\ln x}}$$

I tried to solve it as two limits, in the way that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{2x+3}}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\sqrt[3]{\ln x}}$$

so that the first one is zero, but the second one is not difined for zero.

Can anyone help me to continue?

Thanks.

Comment: $\ln\ln x$ is not defined for $x\leq 1,$ since then $\ln x\leq 0$, and $\ln y$ is not defined for $y\leq 0.$ This makes the limit undefined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks

Comment: Could it be that you were supposed to find the limit rather for $x \to +\infty$?

Comment: @trancelocation No, I check it. If it would be, the answer is 0 I suppose.

Comment: Perhaps the actual limit is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \, \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} \ln(|\ln x|)}{\sqrt[3]{(2x+3)\ln x}}.$$

Comment: If complex numbers are allowed (and you are careful about branches), the limit does exist and is $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I agree! The limit would be 0 in that case!

Comment: For $0 < x < 1$, the principal branch of $\ln(\ln(x)) = \ln(-\ln(1/x))$ is $\pi i + \ln \ln(1/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is how you can see that the limit is equal to $0$:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{x} \log( \log(x)) }{ \sqrt[3]{2x + 3} \log(x)   } = 
  \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{x} \log( \log(x)) }{ \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{2x + 3} \log(x)   } = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{x} \log( \log(x)) }{ \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{2x + 3} \lim_{x \to 0}  \log(x)   } = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{x} \log( \log(x)) }{  \sqrt[3]{3} \cdot (-\infty) } = 
=  \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[3]{x} \log( \log(x)) }{   (-\infty) } 
= \frac{ \sqrt[3]{\lim_{x \to 0} x \log^3( \log(x))} }{   (-\infty) } 
 = ^{L'Hospital} \frac{0}{-\infty} = 0 
 $$

Comment: Is it possible to always do it in this way?

Comment: You have the expression wrong in two ways: 1. the $\log x$ in the denominator should be $(\log x)^{1/3}$ 2. $\lim_{x\to 0}$ doesn't make sense; however, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This limit is bad -- $\ln\ln(x)$ doesn't exist when $x$ is close to $0$. Thus the function itself is undefined in the neighbourhood of $0$ (specifically, undefined when $x<1$, since $\ln(x) \le 0$ here so $\ln \ln x$ is undefined) so you can't say anything about this limit. Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: @Shelley. This shows that, although graphing is not a proof in terms of analytic means, it is very useful. Whenever you encounter some "weird" limit, it doesn't hurt to graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume the question is to find

$$\tag 1 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \, \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} \ln(|\ln x|)}{\sqrt[3]{(2x+3)\ln x}},$$

which is the only thing that makes sense to me. Suppose $0<x<1/e.$ Then the absolute value of the expression in $(1)$ is

$$\frac{|x|^{1/3} \ln(|\ln x|)}{(2x+3)^{1/3}|\ln x|^{1/3}}= \frac{|x|^{1/3}}{(2x+3)^{1/3}}\frac{\ln(|\ln x|)}{|\ln x|^{1/3}} .$$

On the right, the first fraction $\to 0/3^{1/3}=0.$ Because $(\ln u)/u^{1/3} \to 0$ as $u\to \infty,$ the second fraction $\to 0.$ The desired limit is thus $0.$

Comment: Why the second fraction →∞ and not to zero?

Comment: But I said the second fraction $\to 0.$

Comment: You used substitution for |lnx| and I do not understand the part, where you  u→∞. Can you please explain it?

Comment: As $x\to 0^+, \ln x \to -\infty,$ so $|\ln x|\to \infty.$